# Latex - Segoe font - font spec package

Tags: fonts, fontspec, texmaker, linux

I am trying to create a presentation using latex (texmaker) - `Beamer`

I was wondering how to use `segoe` font in latex. I searched the forums like crazy to install the `fontspec` package but I had no luck. 
Here is one [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48002/hand-written-fonts-in-latex-xetex-luatex) I have found. But, I could not get enough information.

> If you really want to dive into using a variety of fonts with LaTeX, I
>   strongly recommend you use the awesome fontspec package in combination
>   with either XeTeX or LuaTeX. fontspec allows you to select any open
>   type font (OTF) that you have installed on your machine using a
>   command like:
>
> ```
> \newfontfamily{\Segoe}{Segoe Script}
> ```
>
> You can find lots of handwriting or calligraphy fonts on sites like
>   FontSquirrel, e.g. here or here.
>
> I also recommend you check out the documentation of the fontspec
>   package because it demonstrates advanced uses of open type features
>   (e.g. stylistic variants), especially with the Zapfino font.

All Credits to `ilpssun`. 
Could some one please tell me how to install the fontspec package on Linux and texmaker

Thanks.

I see that we have to use XeTex package. But the style is not valid anymoroe in that case

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage[british,UKenglish,USenglish,english,american]{babel}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{fontspec}
 \newcommand{\tick}{\ding{52}}
```

Comment: What kind of LaTeX distribution are you using on which platform? If I assume you use TeX Live 2012 on Windows, there is no need to install fontspec since it is already included.

Comment: For hints how to make `Beamer`use Segoe, check out http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=40&t=11261

Comment: In recent TeX distributions `fontspec` already is pre-installed. And XeTeX is not a package, but one of theoutput engines.