# Hand written fonts in LaTeX for Cyrillics

Tags: fonts, cyrillic, metafont, truetype, calligraphy

As shown here [Hand written fonts in LaTeX/XeTeX/LuaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48002/hand-written-fonts-in-latex-xetex-luatex) there are many beautiful hand written fonts in LateX, but all of those for `T1`. Is there something similar to the cyrillics?

Addition to the question:
Can I use True type 2 Metatafont converter to produce font for using with `LaTeX`  (not `XeLaTeX`)? And how can I use generated `.mf`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just search for some font you like (e.g. [here](http://www.911fonts.com/cyrrukopisnye/)), install it on your system and run Xe- or LuaLaTeX like in my MWE:

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
    \setmainfont{41958.ttf}
    Я делаю некоторые тесты, чтобы увидеть хороший почерк.  

    \setmainfont{42714.ttf}
    Я делаю некоторые тесты, чтобы увидеть хороший почерк.

    \setmainfont{42857.ttf}
    Я делаю некоторые тесты, чтобы увидеть хороший почерк.  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But, how about LaTeX?