# How do I set the y axis range in pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Below is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,openany]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}
\tikzset{bullet/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=2pt}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            ymin=0, ymax=10,
            minor y tick num = 3,
            area style,
            ]
            \addplot+[ybar interval,mark=no] plot coordinates { (0, 9.52) (18 868.3692, 9.72) (45 000, 0) };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I wish my diagram to be like the one below (handwritten)[image]

**Current result**:

[image: Current result]

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: Your system of units on the y axis is not correctly set. On your *handwritten* graph, every space between horizontal lines equals 0.2, so that the point of origin is at 8.92, not 0. You have to set your ymin at 8.92 (and change some other parameters if you want to reflect what you drew).

Comment: "No, it doesn't" is not helpful at all. Are you looking for a font that looks handwritten? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48002/hand-written-fonts-in-latex-xetex-luatex

Comment: Im very sorry for the understanding. I wasnt looking for something that looks handwritten. My aim was to produce the output as in that image i posted. @Zarko managed to help with what I was looking exactly.

Comment: @hpekristiansen I think we can delete all these comments about the misunderstanding now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=left,
    xmax=45 000,
    ymin=7, ymax=10,    
    restrict y to domain=7:10,
    ytick=\empty,
    extra y ticks={8, 9, 9.52, 9.72, 10},
    extra y tick style={tick label style={font=\scriptsize}},
    ylabel={Weighted Cost of Capital \%},
    axis y discontinuity=crunch,
    xtick=\empty,
    extra x ticks={0, 18 868.3692, 45 000},
    xlabel={Total financing},
    enlargelimits=0.1,
    area style,
    ]

\addplot +[ybar interval] coordinates { (0, 9.52) (18 868.3692, 9.72) (45 000, 9.72) };

\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It finally worked. I have been struggling to come with this output.

Comment: +1: Hi Zarko. But why the y-axis not is a straight line?

Comment: @Sebastiano, I use it for purpose: `axis y discontinuity=crunch` should indicate that in diagram is part between `y=0` and `y=7` is skipped. By this is "magnified" values between `y=9` and `y=10`. Maybe `axis y discontinuity=parallel` be more indicative.